# foreign key constrain in php code in table creation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `property` structured like this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE property (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            seller_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
            property_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            reg_date TIMESTAMP
            )";
            mysql_query($sql);
```

and I have another table named `dealtype` like this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE dealtype (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            seller_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
            deal_type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES property (id),
            reg_date TIMESTAMP
            )";
            mysql_query($sql);
```

Now the `property_id` in the `dealtype table` is the foreign key of the `id` in the `property` table but its not working in the php code. The `property` table is created but the `dealtype` doesn't get created.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I'm confused, you keep talking about php, but all you show is mysql here (other than your mysql_query function;  btw, it's better to create your tables directly in the database and not using a query, and especially not deprecated code).  Is your question about php or about mysql?   Anyway, as for the foreign keys, are you using an InnoDb database engine?

Comment: thanks for the response .the real question is about adding the foreign key that's why i skipped the php code.yes im using InnoDb database engine ,is my adding foreign key method right?@nomistic

Comment: your syntax is wrong.   here's the MySQL manual on Foreign keys.   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variable with its type *before* specifying that it is a foreign key:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE dealtype (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            seller_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
            deal_type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            property_id int(6) unsigned,
            reg_date TIMESTAMP,
            FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES property (id)
        )";
```

Presumably, `seller_id` has a similar relationship to a `sellers` table (or something similar).

Comment: its still not working ..if i skip the part foreign key line then it work  but when the foreign key line added it doesnt work.@Gordon

Comment: @Etherealsoul . . . Oops, you need the `unsigned` so the types match.

Comment: yes its working thanks a lot..this little problem costs me more than 1.5 hrs!!@Gordon